# SWF built with ANT has different size from built on Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, apache-flex, ant, build

I'm using Eclipse with the Flex Plugin to build a Flex Application that resides inside an EAR. When Eclipse builds the SWF files, and I deploy the EAR on my app server, it works great. But now I need to create a bamboo plan to automatize this build. But ANT is generating those same SWF files with different sizes, smaller. Then, when I try to deploy the EAR on my app server, I got errors:

> Caused by:
>   flex.messaging.config.ConfigurationException:
>   Error instantiating application scoped
>   instance of type
>   'com.pitel.corporate.bo.RemoteReflection'
>   for destination 'remoteReflection'.
>     at
>   flex.messaging.factories.JavaFactory.createFactoryInstance(JavaFactory.java:143)
>     at
>   flex.messaging.FactoryDestination.createFactoryInstance(FactoryDestination.java:252)
>     at
>   flex.messaging.FactoryDestination.getFactoryInstance(FactoryDestination.java:235)
>     at
>   flex.messaging.FactoryDestination.getFactoryInstance(FactoryDestination.java:223)
>     at
>   flex.messaging.services.remoting.adapters.JavaAdapter.validateInstanceSettings(JavaAdapter.java:534)
>     at
>   flex.messaging.services.remoting.adapters.JavaAdapter.start(JavaAdapter.java:346)
>     at
>   flex.messaging.Destination.start(Destination.java:255)
>     at
>   flex.messaging.services.AbstractService.startDestinations(AbstractService.java:649)
>     at
>   flex.messaging.services.AbstractService.start(AbstractService.java:172)
>     at
>   flex.messaging.MessageBroker.startServices(MessageBroker.java:1351)
>     at
>   flex.messaging.MessageBroker.start(MessageBroker.java:277)
>     ... 21 more

And I really know that the problems is with this SWF file, because when I use the EAR that works fine, but changing the SWF files from that built by Eclipse with mine built by ANT, it stops working.

ANT is building the SWF with this:

```
<target name="flex" depends="copyImgs">
        <mxmlc file="${flex.dir}/Pitel.mxml" 
            debug="true"
            keep-generated-actionscript="true"
            compiler.show-actionscript-warnings="true"
            compiler.show-binding-warnings="true"
            compiler.show-unused-type-selector-warnings="false"
            strict="true"
            services="C:/Repositorio/Pitel/Web_FlexVersion/PitelWeb/WebContent/WEB-INF/flex/services-config.xml" locale="en_US">
            <load-config filename="${FLEX_HOME}/frameworks/flex-config.xml"/>
            <compiler.include-libraries dir="${basedir}/libs" append="true">
                <include name="DashboardLayout.swc" />
            </compiler.include-libraries>
            <source-path path-element="${FLEX_HOME}/frameworks"/>
            <source-path path-element="${flex.dir}"/>
        </mxmlc>
</target>
```

If I could export an ANT file from Eclipse to see how it is building the SWF file, maybe I could understand how to set correctly my build.xml

Anyone has an idea about what is happening??

Thanks

Comment: You're probably missing, or using different compiler arguments. Which version of Flash Builder are you using?  Which SWF has the bigger file size?  Are you compiling a debug version to be deployed to a production server?

Answer (score 0):

Try by adding these attribute in **mxmlc**

```
output="${my.swf}"
actionscript-file-encoding="UTF-8"
keep-generated-actionscript="true"
incremental="true"
```

Edited: **Details**

**incremental** is **true** for **FlexBuilder** by default and  **false** for **command line compiler**

and by setting

**keep-generated-actionscript** to **true** compiler wont deletes file which will be generated to build final SWF, it may cause difference in file Sizes.

Please Check [Flex Application Compiler Options](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=compilers_14.html)

Hopes that helps

Comment: Please explain as to why you make these recommendations?  Why would you want to keep generated actionscript in an automated build?  Why would you want an automated build to be incremental?